# definition of stalk at a point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I have come to understand that whenever having a presheaf or sheaf of abelian groups, singeltons are usually not open sets and so there is no way to study its corresponding group. Instead, we like to consider an open set containing the singelton.

The definition above captures this idea for sure, but with a slightly more mature language that I cant grasp. Could someone clarify the idea of "direct limit of groups" here? Or for that matter, the definition as a whole.

Comment: A very good account of this is given in [Ravi Vakil's notes](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), in particular section 1.4.

Comment: @Daniel ill check it out when im at the computer. Do you know if vakils has any notes on abelian varieties aswell? (maybe thats included in the notes you gave)

Comment: @Daniel I am not sure the section helped that much, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: You could also check out exercise 7.6.8 on page 268 in Dummit and Foote's abstract algebra textbook. The treatment in Vakil's notes is very general and categorical but gives a more complete account.

Comment: Is there a particular aspect of abelian varieties you're interested in? References for them include Mumford's classic book along with the section in Griffiths and Harris. A more modern account is given in [milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf) on the topic. All of these require pretty substantial background though.